# Thermodynamics on a very large system

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology

Many physicists use thermodynamics to understand what is happening at a cosmic scale. It feels a bit off. Will most concepts directly apply, or do we need to be cautious while using some formulae?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.